How to find 3 combination of numbers that sum to a specific X Y & Z given a large array of numbers without overlapping?
I have a list of approximately 1000 numbers
I need to break it into 3 non-overlapping groups equaling specific sums
Any suggestions preferably using Excel forumla or VBA?
I tried using the If() and Subtotal() in Excel but got a "false" error towards the end of the list when the remaining numbers did not fit into any existing subtotal
See sample formula with smaller array (where I can easily see if Excel is correct using guess and check)
    =IF(SUMIFS($A$6:A7, D$6:D7, $D$5) + A8 <= 1810, 100,
        IF(SUMIFS($A$6:A7, D$6:D7, $E$5) + A8 <= 850, 200,
            IF(SUMIFS($A$6:A7, D$6:D7, $F$5) + A8 <= 800, 300, "")
        )
    )

I tried running a recursive script in excel macro:
Do Until Range("O4") = True
    Range("O4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("O3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Loop

It only worked on lists of 10 numbers or so; it reached the limit when using longer lists, how can I get it working for longer lists as well?

You got some sample data and an expected result?  It doesn't need to be all 1000.

I'm afraid I cannot clearly understand what are your expectation related to the second issue ("3 non-overlapping groups equaling specific sums"). As required above, it would be good to edit your question and give us some samples (even pictures, if not something editable to be tested...) showing what you have against what you wont. For 10-15 such numbers...

I don't VBA is the best choice here.  You can run Python in Excel and I think it would make a much better tool in this case I think.  Anyway, here's a very clunky, brute force code I have done years ago for a very similar problem.  It works well enough on a small dataset but I have no idea how long it's going to run on your 1000 number input.
    Sub DivideIntoThreeGroups()
        Dim numbers As Variant
        Dim target1 As Double, target2 As Double, target3 As Double
        Dim group1Sum As Double, group2Sum As Double, group3Sum As Double
        Dim i As Long
        Dim assignments() As Integer
        Dim maxIterations As Long
        Dim changeMade As Boolean
        
        ' Load the numbers into an array
        numbers = Range("A1:A10").Value
    
        ' Define your target sums
        target1 = 3 ' Replace with your specific target for group 1
        target2 = 18 ' Replace with your specific target for group 2
        target3 = 8 ' Replace with your specific target for group 3
    
        ' Initialize group sums
        group1Sum = 0
        group2Sum = 0
        group3Sum = 0
    
        ' Initialize the assignment array
        ReDim assignments(LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers))
        
        ' Assign numbers randomly to the three groups
        Randomize
        For i = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
            assignments(i) = Int(3 * Rnd) + 1
            If assignments(i) = 1 Then
                group1Sum = group1Sum + numbers(i, 1)
            ElseIf assignments(i) = 2 Then
                group2Sum = group2Sum + numbers(i, 1)
            Else
                group3Sum = group3Sum + numbers(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i
    
        ' Max number of iterations to adjust the group assignments
        maxIterations = 10000
        changeMade = True
        
        ' Adjust groups iteratively to reach the target sums
        While changeMade And maxIterations > 0
            changeMade = False
            For i = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
                ' Check if group assignments need adjusting
                If assignments(i) = 1 And group1Sum > target1 Then
                    ' Try moving to group 2 or group 3
                    If group2Sum + numbers(i, 1) <= target2 Then
                        assignments(i) = 2
                        group1Sum = group1Sum - numbers(i, 1)
                        group2Sum = group2Sum + numbers(i, 1)
                        changeMade = True
                    ElseIf group3Sum + numbers(i, 1) <= target3 Then
                        assignments(i) = 3
                        group1Sum = group1Sum - numbers(i, 1)
                        group3Sum = group3Sum + numbers(i, 1)
                        changeMade = True
                    End If
                ElseIf assignments(i) = 2 And group2Sum > target2 Then
                    ' Try moving to group 1 or group 3
                    If group1Sum + numbers(i, 1) <= target1 Then
                        assignments(i) = 1
                        group2Sum = group2Sum - numbers(i, 1)
                        group1Sum = group1Sum + numbers(i, 1)
                        changeMade = True
                    ElseIf group3Sum + numbers(i, 1) <= target3 Then
                        assignments(i) = 3
                        group2Sum = group2Sum - numbers(i, 1)
                        group3Sum = group3Sum + numbers(i, 1)
                        changeMade = True
                    End If
                ElseIf assignments(i) = 3 And group3Sum > target3 Then
                    ' Try moving to group 1 or group 2
                    If group1Sum + numbers(i, 1) <= target1 Then
                        assignments(i) = 1
                        group3Sum = group3Sum - numbers(i, 1)
                        group1Sum = group1Sum + numbers(i, 1)
                        changeMade = True
                    ElseIf group2Sum + numbers(i, 1) <= target2 Then
                        assignments(i) = 2
                        group3Sum = group3Sum - numbers(i, 1)
                        group2Sum = group2Sum + numbers(i, 1)
                        changeMade = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            maxIterations = maxIterations - 1
        Wend
    
        ' Output the result to columns B, C, and D
        For i = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers)
            If assignments(i) = 1 Then
                Range("B" & i).Value = numbers(i, 1) ' Group 1
            ElseIf assignments(i) = 2 Then
                Range("C" & i).Value = numbers(i, 1) ' Group 2
            Else
                Range("D" & i).Value = numbers(i, 1) ' Group 3
            End If
        Next i
    
        ' Final output for verification
        MsgBox "Group 1 sum: " & group1Sum & vbCrLf & "Group 2 sum: " & group2Sum & vbCrLf & "Group 3 sum: " & group3Sum
    
    End Sub



Using Excel formulas like IF() and SUMIFS() get really messy and not work well with large datasets. Your VBA script also hit a limit with longer lists. I think you can try to use greedy algorithm and backtracking.
Like this:
Sub SplitIntoGroups()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim numbers As Range
    Dim numArray() As Variant
    Dim group1 As Double, group2 As Double, group3 As Double
    Dim target1 As Double, target2 As Double, target3 As Double
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    Set numbers = ws.Range("A1:A1000") ' Change to your range

    ' Read numbers into an array
    numArray = Application.Transpose(numbers.Value)

    ' Target sums for the groups
    target1 = 1810
    target2 = 850
    target3 = 800

    ' Initialize group sums
    group1 = 0
    group2 = 0
    group3 = 0

    ' Sort the numbers in descending order
    Call QuickSort(numArray, LBound(numArray), UBound(numArray))

    ' Greedy algorithm to assign numbers to groups
    For i = LBound(numArray) To UBound(numArray)
        If group1 + numArray(i) <= target1 Then
            group1 = group1 + numArray(i)
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = 100 ' Group 1
        ElseIf group2 + numArray(i) <= target2 Then
            group2 = group2 + numArray(i)
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = 200 ' Group 2
        ElseIf group3 + numArray(i) <= target3 Then
            group3 = group3 + numArray(i)
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = 300 ' Group 3
        Else
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = "" ' Cannot fit into any group
        End If
    Next i

    ' Output the group sums
    ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Group 1 Sum"
    ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Group 2 Sum"
    ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Group 3 Sum"
    ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = group1
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Value = group2
    ws.Cells(2, 5).Value = group3
End Sub

Sub QuickSort(arr() As Variant, first As Long, last As Long)
    Dim low As Long, high As Long
    Dim mid As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant

    low = first
    high = last
    mid = arr((first + last) \ 2)

    Do While low <= high
        Do While arr(low) > mid
            low = low + 1
        Loop
        Do While arr(high) < mid
            high = high - 1
        Loop
        If low <= high Then
            temp = arr(low)
            arr(low) = arr(high)
            arr(high) = temp
            low = low + 1
            high = high - 1
        End If
    Loop

    If first < high Then QuickSort arr, first, high
    If low < last Then QuickSort arr, low, last
End Sub

